# column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

As I was using Chartkick to install some graphs into my ruby on rails project I am running into a strange error which I cannot resolve or understand other explanations.

The following code I embedded into my view file.

```
<%= area_chart @bets_by_month.group_by_day(:date_of_bet).sum(:profit_or_loss) %>
```

the @bets_by_month instance is declared in the controller like this

```
@bets_by_year = Bet.where("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_of_bet) = ?", params[:year])
@bets_by_month = @bets_by_year.where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_bet) = ?", params[:month])
@bets_by_month = @bets_by_month.order("date_of_bet DESC")
```

Which is returning error when I try to load the page.

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "bets.date_of_bet" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

However when I embed this code into my view file I get no problems.

```
<%= area_chart Bet.group_by_day(:date_of_bet).sum(:profit_or_loss) %>
```

The reason I need to use the instance is because I want each month to have a different graph displaying the results from that month.

Comment: can you post the generated SQL that hits the database when you run the chart code?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
`Bet Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bets".* FROM "bets"
   (0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("bets"."profit_or_loss") AS sum_profit_or_loss, (DATE_TRUNC('day', (date_of_bet::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' AS day FROM "bets" WHERE (date_of_bet IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('day', (date_of_bet::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the graph was getting confused as I had `@bets_by_month` sorted in descending order. Once I changed that everything was fine.